# Save PDF that is embedded in Excel as separate file using phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

using phpexcel  how to I extract an embedded pdf file in an excel worksheet.
I am able to extract images png, jpg   but fail when attmepting to extract pdf file

I tried the code for jpg and png and it is working for theses types but not for pdf

Comment: fails how? An error? Some other unexpected behaviour? It's unclear. Please provide a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. As you're new, I'd also strongly recommend that you take the [tour]. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.